# How to find for a related entity with TypeOrm after upgrade from 0.2.x to 0.3.x?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Given is a nestJS application (0.8) with typeORM (0.2), which contains queries like this:

```
    async findAllForClient(client: ClientEntity): Promise<VaultEntity[]> {
        return this.repository.find({
          where: { client: client },
          order: { createdAt: 'ASC' },
        });
      }
```

`client` is a OneToMany-relation between an Entity ("Value") to another ("Client")

After upgrade to typeORM 0.3 this does not compile anymore:

> TS2322: Type 'ClientEntity' is not assignable to type 'boolean |
> FindOperator | FindOptionsWhere | FindOptionsWhere[] |
> EqualOperator<...>'.   Type 'ClientEntity' is not assignable to type
> 'FindOptionsWhere'.     Types of property 'users' are incompatible.
> Type 'UserEntity[]' is not assignable to type 'boolean | FindOperator
> | FindOptionsWhere | FindOptionsWhere[] | EqualOperator<...>'.
> Type 'UserEntity[]' is not assignable to type 'FindOptionsWhere[]'.
> Type 'UserEntity' is not assignable to type 'FindOptionsWhere'.
> Types of property 'hasRole' are incompatible.               Type
> '(role: string) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'.

For sake of completeness I will post the entities:

**VaultEntity:**

```
@Entity({ name: 'vaults' })
@Unique('idx_unique_uuid', ['uuid'])
export class VaultEntity extends ImmutableBaseEntity {
  @ManyToOne(() => ClientEntity, (entity) => entity.vaults)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'client_id' })
  @Index()
  client: ClientEntity;

  @Column({ name: 'uuid', type: 'varchar', length: 64 })
  @IsUUID()
  uuid: string;
 
  // .... more properties that makes no sense to mention them here
}
```

**ClientEntity:**

```
@Entity({ name: 'clients' })
@Unique('idx_unique_uuid', ['uuid'])
export class ClientEntity extends ImmutableBaseEntity {
  @ApiProperty({ description: 'UUID' })
  @Column({ name: 'uuid', type: 'varchar', length: 64 })
  @IsUUID()
  uuid: string;

  @ApiProperty({ description: 'Associated vaults' })
  @OneToMany(() => VaultEntity, (vault) => vault.client, { cascade: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'client_id' })
  vaults: VaultEntity[];

  @ApiProperty({ type: (type) => UserEntity, isArray: true })
  @OneToMany(() => UserEntity, (user) => user.client, { cascade: true })
  users: UserEntity[];

  // ....
}
```

Can someone pls tell me how to make such queries, where relations and entities are involved, work with typeORM 0.3?